# Pymongo: iterate over all documents in the collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, database-cursor

I am using PyMongo and trying to iterate over (10 millions) documents in my MongoDB collection and just extract a couple of keys: "name" and "address", then output them to .csv file.

I cannot figure out the right syntax to do it with `find().forEach()`

I was trying workarounds like

```
cursor = db.myCollection.find({"name": {$regex: REGEX}})
```

where REGEX would match everything - and it resulted in "Killed".
I also tried

```
cursor = db.myCollection.find({"name": {"$exist": True}})
```

but that did not work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is your actualy query or your desired result? please explain a bit better.

Comment: I am not sure you have tried this or not, try map reduce job to get your work done. Considering huge dataset, it seems to be a better option. Its just a suggestion.

Answer (score 27):

> I cannot figure out the right syntax to do it with find().forEach()

[cursor.forEach()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) is not available for Python, it's a JavaScript function. You would have to get a cursor and iterate over it. See [PyMongo Tutorial: querying for more than one document](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document), where you can do :

```
for document in myCollection.find():
    print(document) # iterate the cursor
```

> where REGEX would match everything - and it resulted in "Killed".

Unfortunately there's lack of information here to debug on why and what 'Killed' is. Although if you would like to match everything, you can just state:

```
cursor = db.myCollection.find({"name": {$regex: /.*/}})
```

Given that field `name` contains string values. Although using `$exists` to check whether field `name` exists would be preferable than using regex.

While the use of [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator in your example above is incorrect. You're missing an `s` in `$exists`. Again, unfortunately we don't know much information on what 'didn't work' meant to help debug further.

If you're writing this script for Python exercise, I would recommend to review:

- [PyMongo Tutorial](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#)
- [MongoDB Tutorial: query documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

You could also enrol in a free online course at [MongoDB University](https://university.mongodb.com/) for [M220P: MongoDB for Python Developers](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M220P/about).

However, if you are just trying to accomplish your task of exporting CSV from a collection. As an alternative you could just use MongoDB's [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/). Which has the support for :

- Exporting specific fields via [--fields "name,address"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--fields)
- Exporting in CSV via [--type "csv"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--type)
- Exporting specific values with query via [--query "..."](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query)

See [mongoexport usage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#use) for more information.

Comment: Some links are not working anymore.

Comment: @AshwaniTanwar I've updated the outdated links. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had no luck with .find().forEach() either, but this should find what you are searching for and then print it.

**First** find all documents that match what you are searching for

```
cursors = db.myCollection.find({"name": {$regex: REGEX}})
```

**then** iterate it over the matches

```
for cursor in cursors
    print(cursor.get("name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` methods returns a `PyMongo` cursor, which is a reference to the result set of a query.

You have to **de-reference**, somehow, the reference(address).

After that, you will get a better understanding how to manipulate/manage the cursor.

Try the following for a start:

```
result = db.*collection_name*.find()
print(list(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I get the question but there's no accurate answer yet I believe. I had the same challenge and that's how I came about this, although, I don't know how to output to a .csv file. For my situation I needed the result in JSON. Here's my solution to your question using mongodb Projections;

```
your_collection = db.myCollection
cursor = list(your_collection.find( { }, {"name": 1, "address": 1}))
```

This second line returns the result as a list using the python `list()` function.

And then you can use `jsonify(cursor)` or just `print(cursor)` as a list.

I believe with the list it should be easier to figure how to output to a `.csv`.