# I want to iterate over documents inside mongodb using callback function in pymongo but I am getting an error in the foreach

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to iterate over documents inside mongodb using callback function in pymongo but I am getting an error in the foreach:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['testing']
collection_currency = db['testcol']
getdata=[]
cursor=collection_currency.find().forEach((data)=>{getdata=data})
df=pd.DataFrame(cursor)
df.to_csv("data.csv",index=False)
```

I'm getting this error

> cursor=collection_currency.find().forEach((data)=>{getdata=data})
>                                                        ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: have a look at the first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899091/pymongo-iterate-over-all-documents-in-the-collection. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes and it should work. The problem is you are trying to use Mongo shell commands with python.

```py
query = {}
cursor = collection_currency.find(query)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))
```

To load a segment of data.

```py
n_documents = 1000
skip_documents = 1000
cursor = collection_currency.find(query).skip(skip_documents).limit(n_documents)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))
```

To write data from the collection to a csv, use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

Comment: thank you but for more than 10 million records it is taking time is there any approach for getting faster

Comment: Depends on what you want to accomplish, if you want to write the mongo data to  a csv (like you've done in the rest of your code), you can use **mongoexport**. You can also  query data to load parts of the data.